# How to extract the results from ubuntu terminal after the execution of a command?

Tags: ubuntu

I run a command (python script.py), but I don't find the resulted file that I hope to have, this execution took more than 3 weeks, now my only solution is to extract the results by using the history of the execution of this command from terminal directly:

I put:

```
history> file.txt
```

But It doesn't give me any solution.

Comment: Please give the script.

Comment: @Björn  the problem is not with the script, I just need a command that lets me same the execution displayed in the terminal

Comment: If your script prints all output to stdout, then calling it with `> file.txt` behind it should put the output in `file.txt`. Since that doesn't happen and a bug in the working in `>` is _extremely_ unlikely, there is probably something with the script. If you don't want to share the script, could you provide an example script showing the same behaviour?

Comment: Quite the same with me. For starters I wanted to know if your script opens a log file by itself or if you use output redirection as @FlorianK described. Piping history makes no sense at all. Please give the command you used to start the script too. Cheers